# Camera suddenly stopped working on B+, still works on Rpi 2

Tags: camera

After few days working with raspberry camera module on a B+ board, the camera suddenly stopped working.

When, for example, I launch raspistill, the camera led lights up, but after few seconds I get following error:
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections etc...

I have checked every connection, disconnected and re-connected several times: flex on rasp side, flex on camera side, sunny connector.

The camera is enabled via raspi-config and seems to be properly detected:

> vcgencmd get_camera
>       supported=1 detected=1

I have tested the module and it works on a Raspberry 2 board, so I guess the problem is not related to the camera itself.
I would also exclude a PSU problem: the red power led on the pi is always on, and the same setup used to work just fine.

I tried also:
- apt-get update/upgrade
- rpi-update to update firmware of the pi board (is there a way to upgrade software of the camera module?)
- reinstall raspbian from scratch (same image installed few days ago, when the camera did work)

What could have caused the problem?
Any idea how I can debug it?

I searched the web for similar problems, but I could not find one.

Thanks!

Comment: CSI port on your RPI seems to be broken.

Comment: @edo1: thanks a lot for the comment; that's my guess, too. do you have any idea about I could double check that? is it possible to do some debugging on the CSI port?